# About GEOquery package usage

Tags: r

I have just started using R. I was hoping to write a program to get dataset from NCBI/GEO and analyze the data to do comparative transcriptomics but couldn't get to make it work. I was wondering if someone has worked on GEO datasets and help with some sample program or guide me through usage of this package.

Thank you,
Avinash

Comment: The [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) is appropriate for this; it does require a subscription and is relatively high-volume, but perhaps a decent investment if you'll do some work in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the vignette for the package: 
http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/1.8/bioc/vignettes/GEOquery/inst/doc/GEOquery.pdf

Install the package based on bioconductor instructions:

http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioc-views/release/bioc/html/GEOquery.html